# MiTM attack on a Tor V3 Onion Service?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, tor, ecc

As far as I understand it, the address of a v3 onion service is simply an ed25519 public key itself. Assuming the end user actually managed to acquire the legitimate 56 character .onion address (i.e. without getting phished/given a fake), would this not effectively render all MiTM attacks impossible?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Jumping from *public key* to *phished* to *MiTM* makes no sense to me?

Comment: Learning URL plays no role in MITM.